# Image not found error when try to get size with Storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get my file size with *Storage size* method.

Error message :

> File not found at path: upload/files/2019/test.pdf

this file is available at public path.

```
$size = Storage::size($fileurl);
```

Comment: I tryed to use public_path($fileurl) instead of $fileurl but nothing changed.

Comment: the `Storage` disks dont point to the `public` folder directly. If you setup the link you will have a folder in `public` named `storage` though, which a Storage disk can reach ... what is the full path to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storage system uses disks, which are specific things with specific root directories. The default disk is `local` which has a root of `storage/app`. There is a `public` disk which uses a root of `storage/app/public`. If you use the artisan command `php artisan storage:link` there will be a link between `storage/app/public` and `public/storage`. If you have placed files in `storage/app/public` they will be publicly available from `public/storage/.....`.

If you have directly put files into the `public` folder and do not have a Storage disk setup to have a root that will allow you to reach that directory you won't be using the Storage system to interact with those files.

You can use the `File` facade to directly interact with the filesystem and not be restricted by a particular disk's root path. In your case you could use the path you have since it is from the root of the project.

```
File::size($fileUrl);
```

If you are going to be dealing with uploads it would be better to setup the link between `storage/app/public` and `public/storage` and using the `public` disk to save files to.

Comment: I used File::size($fileUrl); instead of. Very thanks @lagbox